# Swipe Refresh em TextView

Tags: java, android

Gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de implementar um swipe refresh no android studio para atualizar somente um textview quando acionando?
Estou usando o android studio, a activity tem somente um dois text view no topo estáticos que não mudam,  seis Botões, e por fim uma textview que se altera com o tempo.

Comment: O que você já fez?

Comment: Como não sabia o funcionamento desse widget. Preparei o XML todo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
    new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            updateMessage("Hi, Jarbas");
        }
    }
);

// ...
private void updateMessage(String msg) {
    textMessage.setText(msg);
    swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
}
```

Isso vai atualizar o texto da sua `TextView` e também parar de atualizar o Swipe, se você deixar o método `setRefreshing` como true ou não informar que ele deve ser falso, o **swipe layout** continuará com a animação de carregamento.

Comment: Conseguir aqui galera. Vlw

Answer (score 2):

Na sua classe, use o método `setOnRefreshListener` alterando o conteúdo do seu `TextView`. Só isso:

```
SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe);
swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
       meuTextView.setText("Aqui o novo texto ao usar o swipe refresh");
       swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }
});
```

#### XML

Seu `.xml` pode ser algo nesse sentido:

```
.
.
.
<!-- aqui suas outras views se houver-->

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <!-- aqui suas outras views se houver-->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/meuTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Jon Snow"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


    <!-- aqui suas outras views se houver-->

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Veja mais detalhes aqui em [como usar o SwipeRefreshLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/swipe/add-swipe-interface.html)<sup>en</sup> em sua aplicação.

Comment: Como fica o XML nesse caso? Montei meu XML sem o widget do SwipeRefresh. Todos os objetos do layout(Botões e Textos estáticos) deve se colocar dentro dele, ou só o text view.

Comment: @Joao como você não colocou seu XML, ficará algo próximo disso depois da edição.